# subprocess.check_output is returning an enclosing b' ' string

Tags: python

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/project/.git --work-tree=/path/to/project describe --abbrev=0 --tags
```

returns **release-11.5.5**

I have in my Python 3 code to get the latest release :

```
gd = '--git-dir=' + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.git');
wt = '--work-tree=' + BASE_DIR;
latest_release = subprocess.check_output(["git", gd, wt, "describe", "--abbrev=0", "--tags"]).strip()
```

returns **b'release-11.5.5'**
From where did the enclosing **b''** come from ?

Comment: It's a `bytes` literal: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes - the `b' '` isn't part of its contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Comment: `latest_git_version = str(latest_release).split('release-')[1]` - latest_git_version returns 11.5.5'
- I assumed the trailing ' is coming from the b'' ?